# How to calculate the time complexity of recursive search in maze

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The code is to find a path in a square maze from the start 'A' to the end 'B':
The core function is:

```
def searchFrom(self, row, column):
    if self.laby[row][column] == OBSTACLE: # obstacle
        return False
    if self.laby[row][column] == TRIED or self.laby[row][column] == DEAD_END:
        return False
    if self.laby[row][column] == END:
        self.path.push((row, column))
        self.isFound = True
        return True
    self.laby[row][column] = TRIED
    isFound = self.searchFrom(row-1, column) or \
              self.searchFrom(row+1, column) or \
              self.searchFrom(row, column-1) or \
              self.searchFrom(row, column+1)
    if isFound:
        self.path.push((row, column))
    else:
        self.laby[row][column] = DEAD_END
    return isFound
```

In this case, what's the O(n) for this recursive algorithm.

My understanding is:

```
T(n) = 13+4T(n-1) = 13+4(13+4T(n-2)) = ... = 13(4^0+4^1+4^2+...+4^(n-1))+T(0)
```

so,
the Big O is:

```
O(4^n)
```

Is this correct?

What is the fast algorithm to find a path in maze? DFS or BFS or some else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's correct.

Yes, thinking *locally*, you have a potential fan-out of 4 at each node of your search.  However, *globally*, you cannot visit more than `n^2` locations.  At the leaf node, you will return in **O(1)** time, rather than fanning out.  You can have no more than `n^2` calls that do *not* return in **O(1)** time.

As for depth-first vs breadth-first, consider your maze as a tree-structure graph with only one goal state at a leaf node.  The worst case search in either DFS or BFS is having to visit all nodes.  Since you know that you need to find a leaf node of the structure, the average case will make DFS slightly faster: BFS is guaranteed to visit unproductive intermediate nodes before finding the solution.